# How do the * and + registrers behave in the virtual console?

Tags: register, os-clipboard, selection, x11, console

My Vim is installed with [`+clipboard`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%2Bclipboard) support, and all works just fine.

I know that the clipboard comes with X, so there isn't such a thing in a virtual console (or, at least, this is what I've understood), but...

By pure curiosity, I've just opened Vim in a [virtual console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) (one of those you can get to via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*n*</kbd> for *n* generally from 1 to 5, iirc, as 7 is likely where you are running your desktop env) and verified that <kbd>y</kbd>anking stuff into the `+` register is also automatically stored in the `*` register, and viceversa, because whatever I <kbd>y</kbd>ank into one, then <kbd>p</kbd>utting from either of them results in that text. To give an example, given the text

```
one
two
```

and the cursor being on the first line, hitting
<kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> results in

```
one
two
two
two
```

and the same happens even if I invert the first <kbd>+</kbd> and the first <kbd>*</kbd>.

However, `:registers` doesn't actually list any of the two.

---

To give some gratuitous context which could incidentally help you understand the reason of my question, is that I noticed the `+` and `*` registes don't work in freshly installed Archlinux system where I've installed Vim *with* `+clipboard` support and to which I connect via `ssh`. I have eventually remembered that for the `+clipboard` to be useful and working across SSH, one has to connect via `ssh -X` (or even `ssh -Y`). But apparently that is not enough on this new system I'm referring to. [I've asked a question on Unix.StackExchange as well](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/718636/does-ssh-give-access-to-the-virtual-console-to-a-terminal-emulator-or-what).

Comment: After pasting (`"+p`), `:display` shows the contents of `"` and `0` registers to be what I copied into `+` or `*` register. Interesting.

Comment: I don't know about `0`, but `"` is basically a pointer to the most recently used register, so that's normal.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it doesn't show in the output of `:display`, when you use the plus or star registers in TTS (i.e., a mode without clipboard feature), it stores the content in the `0` register. The code is in the [`get_yank_register`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/ee09fcc9b6cf24e02899461809da9a5148208ea5/src/register.c#L240-L259) function.

If we see the else condition, which is what gets executed in TTY mode for star and plus register (I double-checked with gdb), we'll see it sets the register being handled to 0.

```c
else        // not 0-9, a-z, A-Z or '-': use register 0
    i = 0;
```

The same is true when you're pasting the content (the argument `writing` is false in that case, everything else is the same).

Why the `0` register doesn't display it until it is pasted into a buffer is still a mystery to me. I'll look around and update this answer if/when I find that answer.